# Multiple printing to file

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I'm newbie with python 3.6 and I have question about printing to file multiple times using ssh commands.

I'm trying to print multiple show commands after i create ssh session.
The ssh session established and the first show command works fine (printed to created file).
Any other command isn't working as the first one.

My code:

```
import paramiko 
host = '192.168.100.1'
user = 'MyUser'
secret = 'MyPass'
port = 22
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) #Set policy to use when connecting to servers without a known host key
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
file = open("output/" + host + ".txt", "w")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sh ver')
output = stdout.readlines()
file.write(''.join(output))
stdin.flush()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sh arp')
output = stdout.readlines()
file.write(''.join(output))
file.close()
```

I would like to get assist,
Thanks.

Comment: "Any other command isn't working as the first one." What exactly happens when your code tries to invoke the second command? Do you get any errors or exceptions? What do they say?

Comment: My script is closing so I can't see the error that shown. I tried to find any "pause" command that hold the screen until the user press any key but I couldn't find anything that works.